# Trying to get my program to display the original Matrices

Tags: c++, matrix

I am relatively new to C++ and I have an assignment that is making perform mathematical operations with matrices. I was able to complete the operations but I can't seem to display the original matrices I inputted into the output with out doing a "cout" command for each number. I'm trying to display the original matrices before the answer to the 5 questions.

This is what I have done:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void matrix(int A[3][3], int B[3][3], int result[3][3])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
                result[i][j] += (A[i][k] * B[k][j]);
        }
    }
}
void scalar(int A[3][3], int num, int result[3][3])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            result[i][j] = A[i][j] * num;
        }
    }
}
void display(int result[3][3])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            cout << result[i][j] << ",";
        cout << endl;
        ;

    }
}
int main()
{
    //inputting matrix values
    int A[3][3]={{13,9,7},{8,7,4},{6,4,0}};
    int B[3][3]={{1,3,5},{6,2,-3},{2,0,4}};
    int C[3][3]={{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}};
    int result[3][3]={{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}};

    //question 1
    matrix(A,B,result);
    cout<<"A * B ="<<endl;
    display(result);
    int result0[3][3]={{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}};

    //question 2
    matrix(B,A,result0);
    cout<<"B * A ="<<endl;
    display(result0);
    int result1[3][3]={{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}};

    //question 3
    matrix(C,B,result1);
    cout<<"C * B ="<<endl;
    display(result1);
    int result2[3][3]={{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}};

    //question 4
    scalar(A,2,result2);
    cout<<"2 * A ="<<endl;
    display(result2);
    int result3[3][3]={{0,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}};

    //question 5
    scalar(B,-4,result3);
    cout<<"-4 * B ="<<endl;
    display(result3);
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: "*output with out doing a "cout" command for each number.*": That is the correct way to do it. (Assuming of course you mean using `cout` in a loop as you did in `display`.) There is no other method. It is not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: Do you want to perhaps be able to do something like `cout << "A * B = " << result << endl;`? Just trying to understand the question a little better.